# How does CharacterMovementComponent::PerformMovement work?

Tags: c++, physics, movement, unreal-4

I'm developing an adventure platformer. As such, the manipulation etc. of the `CharacterMovementComponent` is going to be crucial to the game.

I have seen the more top level explanations of the `MovementComponent` however none of them provide any insight into how `PerformMovement` is coded.

I'm trying to work through it and understand it myself, however as i'm not completely familiar with the component, it's a little hard for me to understand.

---

So I was wondering if anyone on here knew anything about this `MovementComponent`, could tell me how the function really works, or could point me in the right direction for the development of our movement systems.

Comment: What aspect of "how it works" are you interested in / confused by? Are you just looking for a line-by-line explanation of the code? What is the problem you are trying to solve or movement style you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Josh

I'm looking for a line-by-line ish explanation of the code. I'm trying to develop a grappling hook, and a custom movement mode is going to be vital. I want to gain a better understanding of how Epic implemented the PerformMovement method so I can understand how to better develop my own system

Comment: Any reason you don’t just ask about implementing the movement of a character with a grappling hook directly? Most of what PerformMovement does may be entirely irrelevant to that problem space.

Comment: Epic implemented performmovement several times in CMC each is entirely different - 2 of the most interesting (atleast for me )are PhysMovement and NavMovement - PhysMovement is implementing by performing many many many traces and based on the results implements the movement. The 2nd one - I have to note that it never worked well for non flat ground is using the underlying NavMesh polys and based on them makes the decisions - it will have all kind of heights problems - but It has significantly better performance (iirc it also doesnt simulatecollisions and physics).

Comment: @ColdSteel So I notice: I've been working through and taking notes - going down the rabbit hole that is the PerformMovement function. I'm gaining an understanding of it. I may post the results here when I've finished my research